# How do you use data from Google Sheets API using swiftui?

Tags: arrays, asynchronous, swiftui, google-sheets-api, xcode14

I am trying to create an app in swiftui in the Xcode 14.2 IDE that extracts data from a google sheets file. I'm currently using the GoogleSheets API and I've managed to create a function that makes a query to get the google spreadsheet. My goal is to read in the spreadsheet and append the data into an array as a SheetRow struct using the following code:

```
func readData() {
   sheetService.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.currentUser?.fetcherAuthorizer              GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.currentUser?.addScopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"], presenting: ApplicationUtility.rootViewController)
  
        sheetService.apiKey = apiKey
        let range = "A1:B5"
        let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet
            .query(withSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range:range)
   
        sheetService.executeQuery(query){ (ticket, result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                //                completionHandler("Failed to read data:\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            guard let result = result as? GTLRSheets_ValueRange else {
                return
           }

            var data = [SheetRow]()
            let rows = result.values!
            let stringRows = rows as! [[String]]
            for row in stringRows {
                let newRow = SheetRow(column1: row[0], column2: row[1]
                // Somehow append data to an array as a return value "returnRows"
            }
        }        
        print(returnRows)
    }
```

My problem is that the part of the function that reads in the data is a query execution that is asynchronous with the rest of the function. I'm able to print within and get the result in the output console, but I want to be able to load that data into an array to have the user view the contents of the spreadsheet.

I've seen other examples of people using the GoogleSheets API for their projects but they were for earlier versions of swift and Xcode.
I would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to extract this data.

I thought the simple solution would be to have a property variable within the struct that I'm calling the function will mutate the variable, but I learned the hard way that the query is asynchronous and would not update the variable within my struct.

In some articles I've read that I need to include completion handling for the query, but I wasn't able to find documentation on how to use it for the GoogleSheetsAPI.